# How to make response codes 200 and 400 consistent in a single query in Postman test

Tags: javascript

I'm currently writing a test for login functionality.

Test code

```
pm.test("status is 200", function() {
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.eql(200)
})

pm.test("status is 400", function() {
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.eql(400)
})
```

Pre-request script

```
const requestJson = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);
requestJson.email = "test@test.com"
requestJson.password = "testtest"
pm.request.body.raw = JSON.stringify(requestJson)
console.log(requestJson)
```

request body

```
{
   email: "string",
   password: "pass",
}
```

If the successful request data is passed, only 200 status tests will pass, and if the incorrect request data is passed, only 400 status tests will succeed.

Is it possible to change the request data just before the success test and change the request data just before the failure test?

If not, do I have to create two queries, one for success and one for failure?

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do? Currently your tests contradict each other. A response can't have both 200 and 400 status. If you want to test, whether the status is either 200 or 400 you can for instance use

```
pm.test("status is 200 or 400 ", function() {
  pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([200, 400]);
})
```

You can also execute additional tests based on the response code

```
if (pm.response.code == 200) {
  pm.test("tests for successful response", function () {
    ...
  })
} else {
  pm.test("tests for error response", function () {
    ...
  })
}
```

But if you really want to use postman for testing, I'd suggest you create separate requests for successful and erroneous requests ...

BTW: An unsuccessful login should return [401 Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) instead of 400 Bad Request

Comment: Should I still create separate queries for failed and successful queries when using tests with Postman?
I asked a question like this because I couldn't find such a case in the document.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "queries". But yes I'd suggest to create two different requests. One with request body that always leads to a success, and one with a request body that always leads to an error. Because otherwise, what value do your tests have, if the testcases randomly (?) fail or succeed?

Comment: By the way, the 400 error is because I am using GQL.

Comment: I'm currently using the postman collection as a query document.
Therefore, I thought that I could complete it with one query, and I intended to ask a question.